# Extract text from a pdf file on Android using iTextG

Tags: android, pdf, itext

When I tried to read a pdf file from sdcard and extracted text from it, nothing happened.
There was no errors, no warnings, notifications and no result file as well.
I stored both the source file and the result in the root folder of device's sdcard.
Could you guys help me solve this problem ?
Here is my code:

```
package com.example.androidtest;

import java.io.File;
...

public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

private Button button;

    public static final String TIMETABLE = "doc.pdf";                       // The original PDF that will be parsed. 
public static final String RESULT = "timetable.txt";                    // The text file received after scan. 


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    processSource();


}   

public void processSource() {

    button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button_add);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              try {
                new MainActivity().extractText(TIMETABLE, RESULT);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });


}

public void extractText(String pdf, String doc) throws IOException {

    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();                    // Load file timetable.txt from device's sdcard
    File file = new File(sdcard, pdf);

    File text = new File(sdcard, doc);                                      // Save the result file in device's sdcard
    InputStream is;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(file);
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(is);                                               // Call the source file
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(text));
       Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 600, 900);                  // Define the rectangle to extract text within it
                RenderFilter filter = new RegionTextRenderFilter(rect);
                TextExtractionStrategy strategy = new FilteredTextRenderListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), filter);
                out.println(PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, 1, strategy));     

                out.flush();

        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }                                               // Call the source file

}
```

}

And here is what it showed in the Console tab when I tested it on AVD (I hope it could help):

> [2013-11-23 03:03:29 - AndroidTest] Android Launch!
>   [2013-11-23 03:03:29 - AndroidTest] adb is running normally.
>   [2013-11-23 03:03:29 - AndroidTest] Performing com.example.androidtest.MainActivity >activity launch
>   [2013-11-23 03:03:29 - AndroidTest] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with >compatible AVD 'Tab'
>   [2013-11-23 03:03:29 - AndroidTest] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Tab'
>   [2013-11-23 03:03:29 - AndroidTest] New emulator found: emulator-5554
>   [2013-11-23 03:03:29 - AndroidTest] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be >launched...
>   [2013-11-23 03:03:57 - AndroidTest] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
>   [2013-11-23 03:03:57 - AndroidTest] Uploading AndroidTest.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
>   [2013-11-23 03:04:06 - AndroidTest] Installing AndroidTest.apk...
>   [2013-11-23 03:04:29 - AndroidTest] Success!
>   [2013-11-23 03:04:29 - AndroidTest] Starting activity >com.example.androidtest.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
>   [2013-11-23 03:04:30 - AndroidTest] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent >{ act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] >cmp=com.example.androidtest/.MainActivity }

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You're using a filter to limit the area to extract text from:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 600, 900);
// Define the rectangle to extract text within it
RenderFilter filter = new RegionTextRenderFilter(rect);
```

A PDF page does not need to have its lower left corner at `(0, 0)`. It can be anywhere in the coordinate system. So an A4 page can be `(0, 0, 595, 842)`, but it might as well be `(1000, 2000, 1595, 2842)`.

Probably the PDF you're trying to extract text from has pages that are outside of the `(0, 0, 600, 900)` rectangle that you use for the filter. This means the filter does not intersect with the page and thus no text is extracted.